# Remote EJB interface not working over internet

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, remoting, amazon-web-services

I have an EJB container that is deployed on JBoss 5.1 on to a Amazon AWS Fedora 8 virtual machine. I have another application which I want to access this EJB container remotely over the internet. But I am getting the following exception

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xxx.xxx.xx.x; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]

Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xxx.xxx.xx.x; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

Here `xxx.xxx.xx.x` is the internal IP of the machine running the EJB.

Here is the code I used to access it

```
Properties props = new Properties(); 
props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory");
props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "<external-ip>:1099");
props.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
props.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
props.put("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://<external-ip>:1099");
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
ic.lookup("EJBName");
```

I have also edited the `/etc/hosts` file like

```
127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost
xxx.xxx.xx.x  hostname  alias
```

and started JBoss with

```
-Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xx.x -Dremoting.bind_by_host=false
```

I guess I have done all the necassary configurations and correct code for this but doesn't seems to work. Please help me solving this issue it has been bugging me for over a week now. And sorry for hiding the actual ips for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

*Connection timeout* It could be a firewall issue. Verify that the port is open: http://www.canyouseeme.org/

You can also try setting the properties: "org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost" and "org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort".

Comment: I'm using the JBoss 5.1 on the client side too. So I think I will not be requiring the ORB port properties for this. The Initial Context returns the Naming stub with the internal ip to the client. But when tried to lookup it gives me this exception.

Comment: Few checks: 1. telnet on EJB port 3700/33700 2. sniffing with wireshark to be sure that a external connection is attempt 3. "netstat -na | grep 3700" to be sure that parameter bind.address is taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Can you telnet on: host address and orb port. i.e. 127.0.0.xxx 3700

If you do not get answer then it's definitely a firwall issue.